# javascript parsing JSON string throwing exception in AJAX workflow

Tags: javascript

I have a Ajax workflow where i read JSON string of length 10,000 - 50,000 in length. Now function i am using for parsing JSON into javascript Object is throwing exception and failing to execute the statement.

Is there some kind on limit on json string that can be parsed, or eval can execute ?

I have tried

1. [YUI JSON](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/json/) utility to parse and
2. Also tried eval() and
3. new Function("return" + jsonString + ";")() also.

But no luck ?
can anybody help me with this problem or suggest something.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is well formed?

Comment: What error message are you receiving? If you can, paste your JSON into http://www.jsonlint.com/ and see if it validates.

Comment: You said it's throwing an exception; there must be *some* information in the exception. It sounds like the JSON isn't well-formed. Try the link Andy E's head gave you, and/or paste the beginning and end of it into your answer (usually the errors I see in JSON are at the beginning or end).

Comment: SORRY ... i was caching wrong exception you are right JSON is wrongly formed ..... jsonlint.com helped finding issue. Thanks all...... for helpfull response. YES ....... it was " again to break it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Thoughts

It sounds like your JSON isn't well-formed. Not seeing the JSON, it's hard to diagnose, but these are the erors I see most often:

1. No single top-level object (the most frequent error here is a top-level array, which is not valid)
2. Improper quotes (all strings, including keys, **must** use double quotes, not single quotes)
3. Functions
4. `undefined`
5. Dangling commas (I'm surprised that http://json.org doesn't say they're valid, actually, that's one of the things Crockford thinks needs fixing in Javascript — and he's not alone)
6. Mis-matched quotes

...although the 2-4 of the above would actually work with the second and third ways you tried to evaluate the JSON, since `eval` and `new Function` both accept full Javascropt object literal notation, which has more quoting options and allows top-level arrays, functions, and `undefined`.

#### "No single top-level object" example

```
{"name": "Fred"},
{"name": "Barney"}
```

Like XML, JSON requires a "root", must be:

```
{"entries": [
        {"name": "Fred"},
        {"name": "Barney"}
    ]
}
```

#### Dangling comma examples

```
{
    "one": 1,
    "two", 2,
}
```

and

```
{
    "myArray": [1, 2, 3, 4, ]
}
```

#### Mismatched quote example

```
{"key": "value'}
```

Comment: +1 for your thoughts, number 2 caught me out early on in my JSON learning - I even filed an IE bug for it lol.  This would be a great answer to the question "What are the most common mistakes I'm likely to make with JSON?"