# Dictionary to Json object, "Expected expression"

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert a dictionery into a json object, so that I can work with it in my front end.

```
sortFields = <%= SchrodersHtmlHelper.ToJson(ViewData["SortInfo"])%>;
```

However, I keep on getting "Expected expression" for this all the time and I'm clueless why. Could anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The conversion works fine, but I still get this issue in the front end, causing the browser to complain about it.

**UPDATE**

The JSON is valid according to http://jsonlint.com/, and the issue is reported as resolved by the OP

```
{
    "Name": "Ascending",
    "ClassDesignation": "Ascending",
    "ShareType": "Ascending",
    "Curr": "Ascending",
    "DateFirstPriced": "Descending",
    "Identifier": "Ascending",
    "OneWeakPerf": "Descending",
    "OneMonthPerf": "Descending",
    "ThreeMonthPerf": "Descending",
    "SixMonthPerf": "Descending",
    "YTDPerf": "Descending",
    "OneYearPerf": "Descending",
    "ThreeYearPerf": "Descending",
    "FourYearPerf": "Descending",
    "FiveYearPerf": "Descending",
    "TenYearPerf": "Descending",
    "SinceLaunchPerf": "Descending",
    "OneYearAnnualisedPerf": "Descending",
    "ThreeYearAnnualisedPerf": "Descending",
    "FiveYearAnnualisedPerf": "Descending",
    "TenYearAnnualisedPerf": "Descending",
    "SinceLaunchAnnualisedPerf": "Descending"
}
```

Comment: What does the resultant JSON look like?

Comment: Do a "view source" and then you can see what the browser got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the JSON in the output isn't well-formed, either because the original is malformed or because it's not being output correctly (or at all, per Pointy's comment). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912087/javascript-parsing-json-string-throwing-exception-in-ajax-workflow/2912205#2912205) for a list of common errors. Since you're using Javascript itself, not JSON, some of them won't apply to you, but some will. My guess is a dangling comma; we need to see the JSON to know.

You can validate JSON with [this validator](http://jsonlint.com/), and learn more of the required syntax on [the JSON site](http://json.org).

Comment: It could be that his construct there is resulting in nothing at all, so that the resulting Javascript is just `sortFields = ;`.

Comment: @Pointy: Indeed, or an unquoted string.

Comment: *[Ed.: JSON moved into question]*

Comment: Have you verified that it looks exactly like that when you do a "view source" on your page?

Comment: Viewing the source doesn't seem to give me much at all.

Comment: Well that right there may be your problem :-)  You should see, in the source, `sortFields = {"Name":"Ascending", ... };` and if you don't then something's wrong with that server-side expression.

Comment: Might this be due it's all in a partial view that causes it not to be displayed in the source? As it seems I can't see any of the information from that page.

Comment: If I'm using FireBug, I can see the object listed in the items under the DOM tab. with the expected values as well.

Comment: jsonlint.com validated his json fine, btw

Comment: The *DOM* tab? Do you mean the "HTML" tab?  In the HTML tab, when you find your `<script>` element and open it up, do you see the code there?

Comment: Yea I know. But the global variable is available in the DOM tab as well. Anyway. Don't know why. I've rolled back my code done back and forward and now suddenly works. When I compare the previous version with this, they are the same. I'm sorry for taking your time. It works no at least!